# How can I rewrite urls (ala mod_rewrite) for free in IIS 6?

Tags: windows, iis, php, iis-6

I've got an application I wrote (with cakephp) for the lamp stack and I'm moving it to a windows server. I'm having a lot of trouble with apache for windows (memory and cpu issues) so I would like to use the existing installation of IIS v6 but it seems to lack any url rewriting ability. I have found expensive addins (isapi) but I don't know enough about IIS or the programs around it to know if any are a good idea.

What works and has simple or compatible to mod_rewrite rules that is hopefully free?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [Ionic's Isapi Rewrite Filter](http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF)
- [ISAPI_Rewrite Lite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/)

If you will need more control over the process, or simply want to learn more, check also these links:

- [Rewrite URL / Implement URL Rewriting in ASP.NET](http://www.aspnetworld.com/articles/2004011901.aspx)
- [A Complete URL Rewriting Solution for ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/a-complete-url-rewriting-solution-for-asp.net-2.0/)
- [Url Rewriting with ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)

Comment: You can check the doc for IIRF online. http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/IIRFhelp
And yes, IIRF is free.

Answer (score 1):

There's an open source project on codeplex called [Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter](http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF) which is free to use.  It's compatible with IIS 6 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Fastream IQProxy is the best soultion with II6s without Apache . Since isapi is no longer packaged with PHP in PHP 5.3.3.3 and replaced with fastcgi